# Selecting rows and columns within .csv file automatically using r

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, p-value

So I have created a database for my thesis and I want to compare substances in different situations to receive a P-value. In order to do this I have created a script in R which is sort of not automatically. I am very interested in how I can create a script which does this for my using a `for` loop. I want to select groups for every line but also every three columns.

[image]

Please let me know if this is possible. Thanks in advance!

Right now I am doing it like this. First select line 1 first three values and then select next three values on first line in order to compare them in the next step.

```
row1_1 <- my_data[1, 2:4]
row1_2 <- my_data[1, 6:8]
```

Comment: What do you mean by `in order to compare them `?

Comment: I want to compare 1A, 1B, 1C with 2A, 2B, 2C. In order to do this, I use the function with two inputs t.test((values 1A, 1B, 1C), (2A, 2B, 2C)). However to do this for every line requires a lot of repeating code, which I would like to automate with a for loop. So: for i in row, select 1A, 1B, 1C, select 2A, 2B, 2C. Is this clear for you guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will use a for loop to go through every row, as per the question

```
for (i in 1:nrow(my_data))
{

case1<- my_data[i, 2:4]
case2<- my_data[i, 6:8]
compare_cases <- t.test(case1, case2, alternative = "two.sided", var.equal = FALSE) 
print(case1)
print(case2)
print(compare_cases)
}
```

Modified variation with error handling, based on the comments

```
pvalues <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(my_data))
{

  case1<- my_data[i, 2:4]
  case2<- my_data[i, 6:8]
  pval <- NA
  test <- tryCatch({ t.test(case1, case2, alternative = "two.sided", var.equal = FALSE) }, 
                     warning = function(war) { NA },
                     error = function(err) { NA },
                     finally = { })
  print(paste0("Test for row i=",i))
  print(test)
  if (identical(test,NA)) pval <- NA
  else pval <- test$p.value

  pvalues <- c(pvalues,pval)
}

print("All my pvalues for all rows are:")
print(pvalues)
```

Comment: I think this works after reading in the data. OP seems to want to do it in `read.csv` or any reading function.

Comment: for every row I want to compare these selected values with each other. I want to use the function t.test(first3values, second3values) and repeat this t.test for every line

Comment: the solution I've provided above would seem to address your question (you'll need to plug-in your t.test() call where the commend says #do compare stuff).

Comment: `for (i in 1:nrow(my_data))
{
  
  case1 <- my_data[i, 2:4]
  case2 <- my_data[i, 6:8]
  compare_cases <- t.test(case1, case2, alternative = "two.sided", var.equal = FALSE)
  print(case1)
  print(case2)
  print(compare_cases)
  
}`

Comment: At the moment I have this piece of code but it still doesnt work... Sorry for the inconvienence

Comment: Can you specify what "doesnt work" means exactly?  And are there any parts that do work or partially work? It would be helpful if you updated your question to provide a reproducible data set that you're working from (the screenshot doesn't help so much since others can't copy paste that into the code to help find your solutions).  I've updated the answer above to include your t.test() additionally

Comment: Sorry, its my first time here, so I really dont know how it works over here. I am really greatfull that you want to help me. The part you did send me works. However, when I add the t.test part it does work untill line 5 and stops. I think it has something to do with 0 values.

Comment: Can you copy-in the error message you're receiving from the interpreter/command-line?

Comment: Error in t.test.default(case1, case2, alternative = "two.sided", var.equal = FALSE) : 
  data are essentially constant

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer.  Better understanding the problem, I've gone ahead and provided an updated one with error handling as well

Comment: I works now! Thank you so much for helping me. As I told you before I am still a new user, so I am not able to upvote you at the moment. Though I am very grateful..